# Deleting elements of lists, within other lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

While doing some Python exercises related to lists and functions, I've encountered this following code:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]


def function (lst):
    del lst[lst[3]]
    return lst


print (function (list))
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

However, in this following code, something different happens:

```
list = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]


def function (lst):
    del lst[lst[3]]
    return lst


print (function (list))
```

It outputs this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 9, in <module>
    print (function (list))
  File "...", line 5, in function
    del lst[lst[3]]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In this case, it only "allows" me to delete until element [2], with the resulting of: `[0, 1, 4, 9]`

I don't understand very well the usage of a list inside a list in this case, and why sometimes it executes as if there were only one list; and other times, the "inner" list has a smaller length.
I would really appreciate if someone could clarify this novice question.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second instance, you see an Index out of range error because the del method is trying to find 9th element in your list. It's like this:

```
list = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]


def function (lst):
    del lst[lst[3]] # Here, python first evaluates lst[3] -> 3rd element from list. Which is 9. And then, evaluates del lst[9] -> tries to find 9th element in list, which doesn't exist. 
    return lst


print (function (list))
```

When you do this:

```
list = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]


def function (lst):
    del lst[lst[2]] # lst[2] evaluates to 2nd element from list, which is 4, and del lst[4] evaluates to 4th element in the list, which is 16 and deletes 16 from list.
    return lst


print (function (list))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because lst[lst[3]] means go to index = lst[3]. For example in your first example, lst[3] = 3 so lst[lst[3]] = lst[3] but in your second example lst[3] = 9 so lst[lst[3]] = lst[9] but the length of your array is 5 so this is why you have an index out of range exception.

Answer (score 1):

```py
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]


def function (lst):
    del lst[lst[3]]. # ok to do this because lst[3] has the value of 3
                     # so basically you are deleting the 4th item
    return lst

print (function (list))
```

```
list = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]


def function (lst):
    del lst[lst[3]]. # here lst[3] is 9 and there are no 10th items in the list
    return lst


print (function (list))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing here is indexing your list based on the value within the list.

So if `list = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]`, `list[3]` equals `9` (4th element).

If you call `list[list[3]]` you are actually calling `list[9]`, which is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to delete the digit at the list index of 3;

```
list = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
def function (lst):
    del lst[3]
    return lst

print (function(list))
[0, 1, 4, 16]
```

if you do `lst[lst[3]]`, first it finds the digit at the lst index 3, in which the value is 9, the deleting `list[9]` gives an index out of range error as the length of the lst is 5: